# TightVNC authentication failed, how to get encrypted password?

Tags: docker, rselenium, tightvnc

I'm trying to set RSelenium with docker following these [instructions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-docker.html).

In "Remote control/debugging with Windows" I noticed something really strange. I installed TightVNC and set the passwords, but I got "Authentication Failed" while using these passwords. The guide said:

> You will be asked for a password which is secret. This can be seen by reading the images Dockerfile:

and there is following code

```
RUN apt-get update -qqy \
&& apt-get -qqy install \
x11vnc \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
&& mkdir -p ~/.vnc \
&& x11vnc -storepasswd secret ~/.vnc/passwd
```

I may be wrong but this seems to me like linux command. Despite of this I tried to paste in docker but I got

```
bash: apt-get: command not found
```

Does this guide need to be fixed or am I missing something? Right now I'm unable to connect and complete VNC debugging.

Answer (score 3):

So you got few things wrong conceptually. The guide is absolutely fine. VNC has two parts VNC Server and VNC Viewer. When you installed VNC locally on your system you may have installed the server version which asks you for password. This password is for you system's VNC Server. With that a VNC Client name `VNC viewer` or something would have been installed also.

Now the docker image that you run hosts a VNC server on port `5901` and the password for connection is `secret`. So the only thing you need to do is Open VNC Viewer, Connect to :5901. When asked for password enter `secret`.

The dockerfile was shown to you for explaining how the author got the password and those commands have nothing to do with your system.

Comment: Argh! I can't realize I could be so stupid.... Too many hours spent trying to learn code I suppose... I'm a totally newbie and I'm doing a full immersion. I guess I should delete this unuseful post but I want to thank you anyway @Tarun!